# Keeping dropdown menu active (visible) even after hover out

Tags: css

My sub menu disappears immediately after I move my mouse pointer to scroll towards the sub menu. Feel like I have screwed my CSS somewhere. I could not figure out after several attempts to make it stay active. I followed few tutorials([have a look at it](http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu)) where they have called the `hover` on the `ul` instead of `a`(anchor), I tried similar ways but could not achieve what I want. Please point out where I have made the mistake. Here is my fiddle([my code](http://jsfiddle.net/zj8krh95/4/)). Sample CSS code for `hover` is below.

```
#topnav ul li ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background:#510000; 
    top:30px;
}
#topnav ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block;        
}
```

Comment: simple remove this line `top:30px;` from #topnav ul li ul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the padding on your list items instead of your ul or container. That way the dropdown overlaps your hover element and your browser never thinks that you hovered out of the element. See this:

```
#topnav li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin-right:30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyTang/q5cmqLrf/1/

Comment: thanks dude this is what i wanted to do..padding fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also give

```
#topnav ul li ul {
   padding-top:30px
}
```

instead of:

```
#topnav ul li ul {
   top:30px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your padding being at the nav level and you trying to make the drop down appear below it. Because you position your dropdown away from the parent li, you're no longer hovering over it when you move your mouse down. To fix, remove the padding from the nav and add it to the li.

remove padding from here:

```
#topnav{
   display:block;
   clear:both;
   width:500px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
}
```

add to here:

```
#topnav li{
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 15px 0 15px 5px;
   margin-right:30px;
   position: relative;        
}
```

remove top from here:

```
#topnav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background:#510000; 
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zj8krh95/7/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do it (it's more of a trick):

http://jsfiddle.net/zj8krh95/5/

```
#topnav ul li:hover {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px; /* so that the menubar's height stays the same */
}
#topnav ul li:hover ul {
    margin-top: -10px; /* so that the menu opens at the right position */
}
```

Basically, on hover, i extend the menu item's height so that no mouseout is trigger when i move down to the menu.

Comment: but i need something similar to that tutorial link i have shared....pls have a look at it

Comment: Well, then you do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zj8krh95/6/. You need to understand how it works and then make it work for what you want to achieve. I didn't give you the solution, but the tools necessary to find that solution.